# Change font on selected text in macro for MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having to add some functionality to an existing macro for MS Word. This particular macro finds a specific text "#code_bar#" in an existing MS Word document and replaces it with a different text i.e. *3541589479*.

Now, once this text is found and replaced (which the macro is already doing correctly), it is meant to change the font to "Free 3 of 9 Extended",which is already imported into Word.

This is the code, which is working properly except the part where I try to change the font and the size, which is actually not taking place. Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
Public Function sustituirCodigoBarras(codigo_barras)

Dim codigoDeBarras As String
Set codigoBarras = ActiveDocument.Content

'#barras_pedido# codigo de barras del pedido

    codigoDeBarras = "#code_bar#"
    With obj_Word.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
        .Text = codigoDeBarras
        .Replacement.Text = "*" & codigo_barras & "*"
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Free 3 of 9 Regular"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 34
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

    End With

End Function
```

Comment: If you do this Find/Replace manually (Ctrl+H for the dialog box) does it work? And if you then record that in a macro how does that code compare to the code in the question? Right off-hand, I'd say the problem might be you need to change this `.Format = False` to `True`...

Comment: You were spot on, .Format = True for those format changes to take place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extra digging and a good-night sleep here's the answer:

- .Format needs to = true in order for those changes to actually take place
- The font name needs to be correct. In my case I was trying to use the *Free 3 of 9 Extended* (which was imported into my computer) and not the *Regular* (which was not imported and therefore not found) as in the code above.

Rookie mistake.

Hope this can help someone else